# How to apply hald-clut to a image in c#

Tags: c#, magick.net

I need to apply a hald-clut to an image in c# with magick.net. I've found how it is done with command-line ImageMagick, but cannot find it in Magick.net. Hasn't this command been implemented? If not, is there another option to do this in c#?

So, my question is how to implement this command in Magick.net:
magick convert C:\images\Myimage.png C:\images\eh_h8_skin.png -hald-clut C:\images\hald1.png

Thanks in advance